# frobot framework - Usage outside testing

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I recently learned how to use robot framework - a testing framework for software / web app testing. It has very simple strong expressive syntax.

I wonder if there is possibility of any other usage of robot framework than testing - I could imagine to create some kind of scraping bot, or checking bot. But so far it looks to me, like it is created strictly for testing (basically whole logic you write in testcases).

**So my question:**

Can robot framework be used outside testing? If yes, can you provide any resources / examples?

Feel free to share any personal experience with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, robot can be used outside of testing. Robot Framework version 3.1 added preliminary support for [RPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation) (robotic process automation). Instead of tests, you can create tasks.

See [Creating tasks](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-tasks) in the robot framework user guide for a bit more information.